# SQL - Run a query against multiple inputs to get multiple outputs

Tags: sql, database

I'm new to SQL and would love to know if this is possible
I have a use case where I have an array of inputs `[1,2,3,4...,1000]` and want to run an SQL query iteratively for the inputs.

Instead of doing this:

```
SELECT * from TABLE WHERE x=1
SELECT * from TABLE WHERE x=2
SELECT * from TABLE WHERE x=3
SELECT * from TABLE WHERE x=4
...
SELECT * from TABLE WHERE x=2000
```

And expect a bunch of outputs.

Comment: What is the max number of inputs?

Comment: It's bad idea... Just use `WHERE x IN (1, 2, 3, 4,...)` and u'll get all data by 1 query

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If there you want x=[1..2000]
you can write:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE x>=1 and x<=2000
```

if the values are random you can write:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE x=1 or x=2 or x=3 ... x=2000
```

or (from the comment of @InDevX)

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE x IN (1,2,3 ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the number is consecutive,you can to use Cte for Generate number

second you can use dynamic query for generate code

finally you can to run query with exec

```
declare @Max varchar(max)=''
;with u as (
    select 1 as n
    union all
    select n + 1
    from u
    where n < 2000
)
select @Max=@Max+ ' SELECT * from TABLE WHERE x=' + cast( n as varchar(100))
from u
option(maxrecursion 0);

exec( @Max)
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell OP which dbms this is for.